# Shortcut to close all tabs on the right, for Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close all tabs on the right of a specific tab, for Firefox or Chrome?

This option to be specific: [Screenshot](https://cld.wthms.co/yzvWO6+)

Or, if there isn't one by default, could this be done with a script?

I looked at advanced settings on the browsers, but haven't found a way so far.

Comment: What is "on the right"? Which object's right side?

Comment: @Biswapriyo, to the right of an existing tab. 

[Image](https://cld.wthms.co/yzvWO6+)

Should have been clear. Let me update the original question as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont find any extension, you can try this: [Tab Manager Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-manager-lite/)

Answer (score 0):

For closing the tabs to the right from the *active tab* this extension works great for Chrome browser

[Keyboard Shortcuts to Close Other/Right Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/dkoadhojigekhckndaehenfbhcgfeepl?hl=en)

Alt+Shift+O to close other tabs
Alt+Shift+R to tabs to the right.